# Terminating an l.split when writing to a file

Tags: python, performance

Basically, I have a function in python that takes in a file from a .txt and gets certain information out of it using l.split. Something happened with the logs I was getting where they aren't coming in uniform anymore. My function tries to l.split at position 18 but now, in some lines of the log file, there aren't 18 entities. I need help writing an if statement or coming up with some way to avoid the index out of bounds error I'm getting. Is there a way I can check if the line in the .txt file contains at least 19 different entities per line and if it doesn't skip that line? Thanks for the help!

```
infile = open('radius.log-20181025.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('goodlogs5.txt', 'w')

for l in infile:
outfile.write(l.split()[+0] +'-') #Gets Day
outfile.write(l.split()[+1] +'-') #Gets Month
outfile.write(l.split()[+3] + ',')  # Gets Year
outfile.write(l.split()[+2] + ',')  # Gets Time
outfile.write(l.split()[-2] + ',')  # Gets Device
outfile.write(l.split() [+9] + ',')  # Gets FSU ID
outfile.write(l.split()[+18] + ',')  # Gets AP, 
outfile.write(l.split()[+19] + ',')  # Gets AP Group
outfile.write(l.split()[+16] + '\n')  # Gets MAC

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. Are you trying to do something like this?

```
for l in infile:
    tokens = l.split()
    if len(tokens) > 19:
        # do something with tokens
```

Comment: Possibly. The problem is, my function is trying to split the 18th element of the line it grabbed, but there's not an 18th element there to split so I get an error. I'd like to put a check so if there's less then 18 elements in the line it grabs, i'd like it to skip to the next line in the .txt file.